# Can I rename opened source file in DrRacket from DrRacket itself?

Tags: ide, scheme, racket

I have source file opened in DrRacket. Can I rename it from DrRacket IDE itself (not using programming language) without closing and opening file again?

Comment: I can't see a way to do this.

Comment: @ignisvolens Some IDEs allow that like VS code. I just thought DrRacket maybe also capable of similar.

Comment: Oh, yes, I think it's a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do: I just don't think DrRacket can (it can do save-as, which will make a copy, as the answer mentions).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `Ctrl+Shift+S` or `File > Save Definitions As...`? That should do the trick.